# Unable to configure a new domain to Digitalocean Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, digital-ocean

I have set up a Wordpress droplet in DigitalOcean and registered a new domain name for it from Name.com. However then as I was following [one official guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-wordpress-one-click-install-on-digitalocean-2#step-5-configuring-a-domain) at Step 5 (Step 5 — Configuring a Domain), when I changed the WorldPress Address to my new domain name, I can't even connect to my Wordpress site both with the original IP address and the new domain. What should I do to configure my new domain?

I feel so confused. Any guide/tutorials I can follow please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://cloud.digitalocean.com/apps, click on your app, and click on the Settings tab. Then, click the Edit link to the right of Domains and the Add Domain button. On the Add Domain form, enter your custom domain name at the top of the form in the text area under "Domain or Subdomain Name," then click to proceed.

Read more:

[How to Manage Domains in App Platform - Digital](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/manage-domains/#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20https%3A%2F%2Fcloud,Name%2C%20then%20click%20to%20proceed.)
[How to Add Domains - Digital Ocean](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/dns/how-to/add-domains/)